# Toggle visibility of unchanged files in magit-status

Tags: magit, visibility, magit-status

I want to rename a number of tracked but unchanged files via `magit`. I know that I can use `R` (`magit-file-rename`). However, `magit-status` does not show me unchanged files.

How can I toggle the visibility of the unchanged files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a section with 'tracked-files' to the git status buffer using

```lisp
(magit-add-section-hook 'magit-status-sections-hook
                        #'magit-insert-tracked-files nil t)
```

(refresh the git-status buffer after adding the hook function).

Read the docstring of `magit-add-section-hook` to find how to control the insert location of the new section.

I guess there is no need to 'toggle' it as you can just fold/unfold the section.

Toggling the section is not supported, you would have to write your own function for that.

B.t.w. there is also the `vc-dir` command (`C-x v d`), which might be more useful for listing files in a single dir (and there is `vc-rename-file` also).

Comment: I was thinking I could toggle the visibility of the section, but as you point out, folding and unfolding the section is sufficient.  Regarding ```vc-dir```, something seems to be wrong with my setup. The VC-Backend, working dir, branch and stash status are OK, but the remote is missing and, more importantly, no files or directories are listed, just ```./```.

Comment: I think `vc-dir` lets you choose a single directory to list. That's why I mentioned it might be handier 'only' when listing files in a single dir. I am otherwise not sure how it works, I have never used it (just found it while answering here)